# Extract version using shell commands

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cut

I am trying to extract version from below mentioned URL's using shell commands like, grep, awk, sed, cut which ever is most suitable

```
https://abcd/efgh/1.1.3/hijkl/mnop    
https://abcd/efgh/hijkl/2.3.4.5/mnop    
https://abcd/3.4/efgh/hijkl/mnop
```

I am looking to extract the version(numbers with dot) alone from the URL, where the position may vary as in above example. Looking for suggestions.

Expected output to be :

```
1.1.3
2.3.4.5
3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+' file

1.1.3
2.3.4.5
3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+/){   ##using match function to match regex of ([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+ in current line. 
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Printing sub string of matched regex above, starting index is RSTART till value of RLENGTH here.
}
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
https://abcd/efgh/1.1.3/hijkl/mnop    
https://abcd/efgh/hijkl/2.3.4.5/mnop    
https://abcd/3.4/efgh/hijkl/mnop
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[/\n]"}/^[.[:digit:]]+$/' file.txt
```

output

```
1.1.3
2.3.4.5
3.4
```

Explanation: I specify row seperator (`RS`) as either `/` or newline (`\n`) then print only rows (i.e. parts between / or newline and / or / and newline) which contain only `.` or digits - in order to achieve such effect I use `^` and `$` denoting start and end of record.